# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: adb is not defined

Tags: node.js, sqlite

When better-sqlite3 is called it returns

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: adb is not defined
```

anyone know why/how to resolve?  I am on Windows and already went through the full Windows install troubleshooting steps that are found here https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I'm a fool sorry, it was a typo